# Why cordova is showing Error: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 414 in Angular using ionic 1?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating android app using ionic 1 and angular js. This is first time I am observing this issue.The issue is am running my project using command 'ionic serve'everything is working fine(app is working fine on browser) but when I am using 'ionic run android' command it is throwing this error on command prompt 
'Error: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 414'

Further more when I copied and pasted www folder and replaced that folder with android asset's www folder (to reflect changes  of root www's folder) and open the directory in android studio the code is running.App is working fine without any error showing.
My question is why is that erorr occurring? Under what file's position 414 unexpected token it is talking about(I have many controllers available so I am not able to find what controller 
or any other javascript file it is talking about)
Attached is the error screen shot
[image]

This error comes whenever I run command 'ionic run android'

Comment: what is showing up at - position 414 ? ..have u checked the JSON ?

Comment: in what file should I check? I mean first screen is login and attached controller is loginController, And this controller does not have 414 lines of code.Hardly it will have 5o lines of code.In this case what file should I check?

Comment: what json you are talking about?

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshot where you are getting error

Comment: sure .. editing now

Comment: I have resolved position 414 issue but now here come another issue as mention in picture position 776 :(

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time, I have finally figured out the problem. Due to merge conflicts over gitlab, some part of the code was missing from plug in.So, I un-installed my plug in(in my case I was using cordovaImagePicker plugin) and installed the same plug in. And everything started working fine as expected.